# Blender 2.82 viewport and tab selection lag

Tags: interface, performance

So I downloaded Blender 2.82 for Windows 10 and right away noticed lag in the 3d-Viewport. Just grabbing and moving the cube was noticeably laggy. Other basic functions like rotation and scaling were also delayed. I have used Blender 2.78 without any such lag in my old laptop that had i5-6xxx and 4 GB ram. My current laptop has a i5-1035G1 with 8 GB ram with built in graphics and it shows the lag!!. I monitored the CPU usage, it was about 4% at idle and 25% while moving the cube and 315 MB was the memory usage.

- I read another article [Blender viewport lag](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/94184/97631) were it was
  suggested that I download Blender from steam but that too did not 
  help.
- I have also tried loading factory settings but that was a fail too.

  Could someone tell me what the fault  is...Is my computer not capable to handle this software or is there some bug in the software.
  Here is the system info obtained from blender...

````
    version: 2.82 (sub 7), branch: master, commit date: 2020-03-12 05:06, type: Release
    build date: 2020-03-12, 15:41:08
    platform: Windows
CPU device capabilities: SSE2 SSE3 SSE41 AVX AVX2

OpenCL device capabilities:
Number of platforms: 1
Platform #0
    Platform Name: Intel(R) OpenCL
    Platform Vendor: Intel(R) Corporation
    Platform Version: OpenCL 2.1 
    Platform Profile: FULL_PROFILE
```
````

Comment: Is your GPU supported, and does it have the latest drivers installed?

Comment: Yes all latest drivers are installed and i have inbuilt GPU from intel...